# How do I choose an optimizer for my tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow seems to have a large collection of optimizers, is there any high level guideline (or review paper) on which one is best adapted to specific classes of loss functions ?

Answer (score 17):

It depends on your datasets and NN models, but generally, I would start with Adam. Figure 2 in this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) shows Adam works well.

[image]

Also, you can see a very nice animation from
http://www.denizyuret.com/2015/03/alec-radfords-animations-for.html.

[image]